# Different ways of writing a XWPF file

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

So I want to automatize the creation of a Proof Of Payment so I create it and it automatically fills the info of each client. 
The way that I'm trying it now is to replicate the word document through the Apache-Poi so I put it into a loop and fill the info for each client.

**The problem is:**

- The document is a little bit complicated and I'm also having problems with `Apache-Poi` is there a different way to do it?

**Example:** 
A function like `document.toJavaCode()` can have the text and just copy & paste it or maybe a way to just have the empty document and just fill the right blanks by iterating the document and finding the blanks I need to fill.
 
Or trying to copy the document through the Apache-Poi XWPFTable/XWPFParagraph is the only way to do it?

Comment: The solution I have found is that you can run a loop which will number every blank cell , so you know what to write where